# intermittent ssl certificate errors on a rackspace load balancer

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, rackspace

Below are two connection made seconds apart. 
As you can see one of them succeeds on retrieving the ssl certificate and the other don't.

Have anyone seen this before? I can't find info about it.

**FIRST:**

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -status -connect www.myapp.co.uk:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
OCSP response: no response sent
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:0
- ---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=myapp, Inc./OU=myappshipping(UK)/CN=www.myapp.co.uk
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
- -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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- -----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
- -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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- -----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
- -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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- -----END CERTIFICATE-----
- ---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=myapp, Inc./OU=myapp(UK)/CN=www.myapp.co.uk
issuer=/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
- ---
No client certificate CA names sent
- ---
SSL handshake has read 4279 bytes and written 643 bytes
- ---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID:
6CC8E831C13BAE68C7FB2E43F4E3552866F17F734BF425199DE79083CCEAD622
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
E09C83C3CE6DA1F11795CC2C3924D6C48A54BB63CB6A5FDAF389E619B5C97B00215E3A2E6872081E07A3B562045AE835
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1407940165
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
- ---
^C
```

**SECOND:**

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -status -connect www.myapp.co.uk:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139677867542184:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake
failure:s23_lib.c:177:
- ---
no peer certificate available
- ---
No client certificate CA names sent
- ---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 329 bytes
- ---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
- ---
```

if I try a curl this is what happens:

```
$ curl -v https://www.myapp.co.uk
* About to connect() to www.myapp.co.uk port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 37.188.111.150...
* connected
* Connected to www.myapp.co.uk (37.188.111.150) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.myapp.co.uk:443
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
www.myapp.co.uk:443
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was that the client servers were being blocked because of the high number of requests. Rackspace load balancers have the option to allow IPs or networks, after I created an access rule for the client IP, the problem was solved.

I arrived at this conclusion because SSL configurations either work or not, they don't get intermittent so the problem needed to be somewhere else, apart from that we tested the same call from other servers and worked every time